# JWT differences between Programming Languages

Tags: python, ruby, jwt, token

I've got an API written in Python and another written in Ruby. We need these to send data between themselves and have decided to use JWT's as an authentication method. Basically generating a token on either end and making sure they match up. Now I'm having issues with matching hashes between python and ruby. Given this code : python (2.7) PyJWT == 1.6.4

```
>>> import jwt
>>> jwt.encode({"someKey":123}, "secret", algorithm='HS256')
```

> u'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lS2V5IjoxMjN9.DL8qyWMeqfMMLCTPN3RA9K08e-AkNW_ybPyywvrIIZ8'

This also seems to change between python versions - running this as python3 produced this

> b'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJhcHBlbklkIjoxMjN9.YgFKZePJYMRDMgubCeZBy6WaFKiTA9C-TRnnZLFJC8E'

Then when I create a similar 'function' in ruby I get a different hash - This is also true between versions of ruby's jwt (I've tested jwt-1.5.6 and jwt-2.1.0) - below is the jwt-1.5.6 result.

```
require "jwt"
someKey = 123
secret = "secret"
payload = {"someKey" => someKey}
token = JWT.encode payload, secret, 'HS256'
puts token
```

The output of that code is

> eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lS2V5IjoxMjN9.7Ch3o7IXmxqm79AcrTetXuZv6h3suyLD5_IgXdrRlNs

With version jwt-2.1.0 I get:

> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzb21lS2V5IjoxMjN9.QkKm2IuvOz_D5ukIxOsjMYApzV2ZnjLE2HII3ZfP_hsWith

Why would the output of these two code set produce two different hashes?

EDIT:
When I use jwt.io

https://jwt.io/#debugger-io?token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzb21lS2V5IjoxMjN9.DL8qyWMeqfMMLCTPN3RA9K08e-AkNW_ybPyywvrIIZ8

i get the same token as for python

Comment: Does jwt 1.5.6 and jwt 2.1.0 use the same hashing function?  Are you hashing the same data (dicts in python are not JSON)?  Interesting question, but from a design standpoint, you probably shouldn't be doing this :)

Comment: You can only use a dict with the python side (jwt.encode only accepts dicts) - but for the Ruby side that function accepts a dict or a JSON string - both do not match.

Comment: Didn't look much at the code, but Python switched to Unicode strings by default in Python3, which was not the case in Python2. Could that be causing the different outputs? Add a `u` to the string using Python2 and see if the outputs match then.

Comment: if you inspect all JWTs on JWT.io you can see different order of the header fields (but identical values), only the second ruby example is missing the `typ` header. The payload is `"someKey":"123"` but in python3 it changed to `"appenId":"123"`. No wonder the result is different.  The idea of JWT is not to produce identical tokens to compare them but to have a signature which enables you to validate the token itself.

Answer (score 0):

So I worked this out and as @jps mentioned the Ruby code doesn't have the header {"typ":"JWT"} - the python code does. As mentioned in the docs for ruby [jwt](https://github.com/jwt/ruby-jwt#add-custom-header-fields) you can set the header. This was the code that fixed it on the ruby end.

```
token = JWT.encode(payload=payload, key=key, algorithm='HS256',header_fields={ typ: 'JWT' })
```

With that the tokens now match. BTW the hashes, even though different, are able to be decoded by the same secret - there was just an extra step in auth that double checked if the hash ruby created matched the incoming hash.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to create a token in both sides.
Use JWT strategy with a pub priv key algorithm like `RS256`. With this you can sign the JWT token in one API and able to verify with a public key in your other API.

Comment: I totally agree with you. I didn't design the auth method, and changing it would break many many parts.